# STL nested containers dereferencing error

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

I'm pretty rusty in my C++ and what little STL knowledge I once had.  I'm particularly struggling to read the voluminous error messages generated.

Given:

```
typedef map<string,int>layerType;
typedef vector<layerType> aggregateLayersType;
```

What's wrong with:

```
bool LayerManager::use_layers(aggregateLayersType& layers)
{
  int layerVal = layers[0]["ts"];
}
```

The error is:

```
> No viable overloaded operator[] for type
> 'std::__debug::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
> std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >'
```

I'm sure it's going to be something simple once someone points out the obvious.

Comment: Using what compiler and standard library?  Visual C++ 11 Beta and g++ 4.7 both accept the code as-is, assuming you've included `<map>`, `<vector>`, and `<string>`.

Comment: OS X, 10.7.3, Xcode 4.3.2, LLVM 3.1.  And yes, I have included `<map>`, `<vector>` and `<string>` headers

Comment: Do you use `libc++`, and if not, what is the version of gcc that is installed on your computer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the debug version (std::__debug::map) of the std::map class: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00298.html

which lacks the overloaded `operator[]` according to the documentation.

Whereas it's present in the release version: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00601.html

Try prefixing your map typedef with std::

`typedef std::map<string,int> layerType;`

I suspect that their might be some namespace leakage elsewhere in your code where std::__debug is leaked ....

Comment: Hmm...interesting...I certainly don't recall explicitly selecting a debug library.  I assume Xcode did that on its own.  Would that be considered an Xcode problem, or an STL bug?

Comment: @wadesworld: What are the flags passed to the compiler? I'd look for _GLIBCXX_DEBUG or something similar that's telling it to use the debug parts of libstdc++...

Comment: @wadesworld: Or check for namespace leakage of std::__debug.

Comment: OK, time to fess up for an embarrassing mistake.  Somehow in my preprocessor settings, _GLIBCXX_DEBUG got set for my debug build.  I honestly have no idea how or why I set that at some point, but removing it resolved the problem.  Thanks @sashang for pointing me in the right direction of what to look for.

Comment: The debug mode map inherits operator[] from its (non-debug mode map) base class, it's just not shown in the doxygen API docs. The debug mode classes should have the same interface as the non-debug mode versions. I have no idea what "namespace leakage" means but no such thing should be possible.